# iOS5 Custom Tab Bar

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile

I am new to Iphone and I have started an application in which I have added a custom tab bar which has to load to some particular page only. The tab bar works as per my expectation. Now the problem is that, when I navigate to other pages the tab bar keeps on showing and it cause serious problem for me... 
Here is my implementation

In .h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class MainMenuViewController;

@interface RoutineListViewController : UIViewController<UITabBarDelegate>{
    MainMenuViewController *homeBtn;

    UITabBar *mainTabBar;
    UIViewController *routineTabViewController;
    UIViewController *calendarTaViewController;
    UIViewController *editTabViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBar *mainTabBar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *routineTabViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *calendarTabViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *editTabViewController;

- (IBAction)goToHome:(id)sender;

@end
```

In .m, i am implementing the tab as:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {
    switch (item.tag) {
        case 1:
            if (routineTabViewController == nil) {
                self.routineTabViewController =[[RoutineListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RoutineListViewController" bundle:nil];
                [self.view insertSubview:routineTabViewController.view belowSubview:mainTabBar];
                routineTabViewController = nil;
                [routineTabViewController release];
            }

            break;
        case 2:
            if (calendarTabViewController == nil) {
                self.calendarTabViewController =[[CalendarTabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CalendarTabViewController" bundle:nil];
                [self.view insertSubview:calendarTabViewController.view belowSubview:mainTabBar];
                calendarTabViewController = nil;
                [calendarTabViewController release];
            }

            break;
        case 3:
            if (editTabViewController == nil) {
                self.editTabViewController =[[EditTabViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditTabViewController" bundle:nil];
                [self.view insertSubview:editTabViewController.view belowSubview:mainTabBar];
                editTabViewController = nil;
                [editTabViewController release];
            }

            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

And when I implement a button to go to some other page, the tab bar keeps showing. Here is the button implementation in EditTabViewController.m file.

```
- (IBAction)goToHome:(id)sender {
    homeBtn = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubview:homeBtn.view];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per Apple's rules, a TabBarController is *supposed* to be the main container. Plus, if you just implement a custom `UITabBar`, are you using that to push the user into other views? If so, if the `UITabBar` disappears, how does the user ever return?

If you only want the bar visible when a particular page is visible, why not implement a `UINavigationController` (as the main container) and have the root `UIViewController` implement a `UIToolbar` that performs the same functions. Then, when you navigate to another page (I'm assuming here that you mean a new screen, not a different page in a `UIPageControl` or a web page in a `UIWebView`), you push in a new `UIViewController` that doesn't contain the `UIToolbar`.

Kind of like this:

```
--UINavigationController
   |
   -->UIViewController as RootViewController --> Contains UIToolbar
      |
      -->Pushes UIViewController --> Has no UIToolbar
```

---

***Edit/Update***

I just saw your code, and I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. I think you might be trying to somehow implement behavior similar to a `UINavigationController` without actually using one.

---

***Edit/Update #2***
I think you are wanting behavior that can be implemented like this:

```
UINavigationController (containing IconMenuViewController as RootViewController)
|
--> PageViewController (push into this from any icon touch in IconMenuViewController)
       --> Contains UIToolbar/UITabBar
```

If you use the hierarchy above, the `UINavigationController` will automatically provide you with the `NavigationBar` at the top of the screen and give you a back button. As long as you make the `UIToolbar` or `UITabBar` part of the `PageViewController`, it should appear and disappear with its view controller as you push and pop it. Does that make sense?

Comment: What I am trying is that... I have a UIViewController with some menu icons. When I click on any meny icon, it will take me to a Page which contain Three Tabs and at top there is a "Home" button to go back to the main menu (from where the tab bar page is coming). I have implemented everything using above code but when I click to "Home" button it takes me to Main menu page but with the Tab Bar in bottom. I don't knw my code is correct/feasible or not. Kindly help me.

Comment: As I mentioned, it sounds to me like you might rather use a `UIToolbar`, but in any case, it sounds like you **DON'T** have a setup that is using a `UINavigationController`. You should take a look at navigation-based apps, because I think they would automatically manage some of the features with which you're struggling.